# Appium parallel execution on two device issue

Tags: java, testng, appium, selenium-grid, appium-android

Hello I have very strange issue with Appium parallel execution for 2 devices

What I have:

1. android device1
2. android device2
3. Two selenium grid node with different Appium servers 
   (and i try make the same but with one appium server but with 2 different systemPorts)

Every time when I run tests in parallel, 2 threads get started on the same device (instead of two devices) and my test crashes.

my code:

testng.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="BDD Test Suite" verbose="1" parallel="tests" thread-count="2">
    <test name="Honor 8">
        <parameter name="platformName" value="Android"/>
        <parameter name="deviceName" value="HUAWEI1"/>
        <parameter name="platformVersion" value="7"/>
        <parameter name="udid" value="value1"/>
        <parameter name="port" value="4740"/>
        <parameter name="systemPort" value="8201"/>
        <classes>
            <class name="global.APP.starter.TestExample"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="Honor 10">
        <parameter name="platformName" value="Android"/>
        <parameter name="deviceName" value="HUAWEI2"/>
        <parameter name="platformVersion" value="9"/>
        <parameter name="udid" value="value2"/>
        <parameter name="port" value="4750"/>
        <parameter name="systemPort" value="8200"/>
        <classes>
            <class name="global.APP.starter.TestExample"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

TestExample:

```java
package global.APP.starter;

import global.Drivers;
import org.testng.annotations.*;

public class TestExample {

    public Drivers drv = new Drivers();
    @Parameters({"platformName","deviceName","platformVersion","udid","port","systemPort"})

    @Test
    public void testLoginAndLogout(String platformName, String deviceName, String platformVersion, String udid, String port, String systemPort) throws Exception{
        drv.MultipleDriver(platformName, deviceName, platformVersion, udid, port, systemPort);
    }
    @AfterMethod
    public void treadDown(){
       drv.closeDriver();
    }
}
```

**Drivers.java**

```java
import com.codeborne.selenide.WebDriverRunner;
import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.MobileDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.AndroidMobileCapabilityType;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.testng.Assert;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Drivers {

    public static AppiumDriver<WebElement> driver;
    public static DesiredCapabilities cap;

    public AppiumDriver MultipleDriver(String platformName, String deviceName, 
                                       String platformVersion, String udid, 
                                       String port, String systemPort) throws MalformedURLException {
        cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
        if (platformName.equals("iOS")) {
            cap.setCapability("platformVersion", platformVersion);
            cap.setCapability("bundleId", "com.app.app");
            cap.setCapability("platformName",platformName);
            cap.setCapability("deviceName", deviceName);
            cap.setCapability("udid", udid);
        }
        if (platformName.equals("Android")) {
            cap.setCapability("app", "/Users/usr/Desktop/app/app.apk");
            cap.setCapability("platformName",platformName);
            cap.setCapability("deviceName", deviceName);
            cap.setCapability("udid", udid);
            cap.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.SYSTEM_PORT, systemPort);
            cap.setCapability("automationName", "UiAutomator2");
        }


        cap.setCapability("noReset", true);
        cap.setCapability("fullReset", false);
        if (platformName.equals("iOS"))
            driver = new IOSDriver<WebElement>(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:" + port + "/wd/hub"), cap);
        else if(platformName.equals("Android"))
            driver = new AndroidDriver<WebElement>(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:" + port + "/wd/hub"), cap);
        Assert.assertNotNull(driver);

        WebDriverRunner.setWebDriver(driver);

        return driver;
    }

    public static AppiumDriver getDriver() {
        return driver;
    }

    public void closeDriver(){
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Please let me know what is being done incorrectly in my code.

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies in your `Drivers.java` class.

you currently have the following in it

```java
public static AppiumDriver<WebElement> driver;
public static DesiredCapabilities cap;
```

So when you spin off two test executions in two threads, both your tests are trying to instantiate `driver` object and set them to the same static instance. That is why both your tests end up targetting the same device.

To fix this, please declare both `driver` and `cap` as instance variables in `Drivers.java` (i.e., remove `static` keyword from their declaration) so that they look like this

```java
public AppiumDriver<WebElement> driver;
public DesiredCapabilities cap;
```

Answer (score 0):

Parallel execution with Appium Studio is easier than the native appium approach.
They have support for cloud devices as well.
Check out [this](https://docs.experitest.com/display/public/TD/SeeTestAutomation-+Parallel+Execution) documentation for parallel execution.