# How to implement parallel testing across multiple devices with Appium and TestNG

Tags: testng, appium, parallel-testing

Unable to achieve the parallel test execution using sytemport capibilities

I'm currently working on achieving parallel execution of test cases on multiple Android emulators. I attempted to implement this using the "systemport" capability and included the "@parameter()" annotation, but unfortunately, I didn't achieve the desired results.

I consulted the following resource for guidance: https://medium.com/@setpace/parallel-execution-in-appium-1-7-dc60c4802082
https://discuss.appium.io/t/how-to-connect-multiple-android-devices-with-appium/8234/8
[Appium parallel execution on two device issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55157494/appium-parallel-execution-on-two-device-issue)

I would greatly appreciate assistance in identifying any steps I may have overlooked and any specific configurations that might be necessary on the Appium side. It's important to note that in my case, Appium is programmatically started, and the app is passed as a parameter from the "global.properties" file within the Capabilities.

Thank you for your help.